# Hanging a TV mount on a old wall with metal studs

Tags: drywall

I am hanging a TV in my condo.  The condo was built in 1967.  The wallboard is very thick, around 3/4" with less then 2 inches behind the wallboard.  I was going to use GripIt anchors but they only go up to 5/8"  I then tried Hilti HTB-2 Hollow wall metal anchors but the toggle is to long to make it all the way into the hole so that it can spring out.

I am wondering if I take the two lag bolts that came with the mount and screw them through the drywall and metal studs if that would hold.

The TV is 40 pounds but the mount can extend 18" so I am worried about torque.

Anyone have any suggestions of a anchor I can use?

Comment: So they used 2x2 studs?? what kind of wall behind the wall board?

Comment: It is concrete but I discovered I could drill through the back of the stud an tha allowed me to get the anchor in an with some wiggling  I was able to get the anchor to unfold!

Comment: sheet-metal studs are hard to anchor point loads to as they tend to bend and tear, there is a special fastener that anchors to the concrete and avoids loading the drywall, but I forget what it's called.

Comment: You could just drill into the concrete and insert those lead anchors and then lag bolt the tv to the wall.